# Can't install Watin for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, watin, .net

I want to install Wating for Visual Studio 2010. I saw their Video on the website, and followed the steps, but I got some errors while installing NuGet.

This is what I did now:

1. New project -> C# Form
2. Project -> Add reference -> Added the Net 4 DLL WatiN.Core.dll
3. Added this code to my project (from their website, which is added to the source below)

And I get this errors:

'Form' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' and 'WatiN.Core.Form'
'WatiN.Core.Form' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context

Here is my application code (I added using Watin.Core too):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
            browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

            Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));

        }
    }
```

What do you think ?

Comment: You probably need to add `using Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form` at the top of your C# file.

Comment: thanks, but now I get this :Error 2 The type or namespace name 'WatiN' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have `using WatiN.Core;` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `System.Windows.Forms` and `WatiN.Core` contain definitions of `Form` class. My suggestion is to delete both(one of) the references to `WatiN.Core` and `System.Windows.Forms` and manually resolve the issues like so:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
```